# GLSL error: Most Likely something simple :/

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have come across this error upon compiling my program:

```
ERROR: 0:1: '#version' :  syntax error
ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline
```

I am sure it is something so trivial and my google searches are probably too specific. My question really is:

"What does this error mean?"

GLSL code is available if needed.

FIX:

As derhass magically pointed out without seeing my code, I was loading the GLSL line by line, however not properly adding a newline to the string:

```
while((line = shaderReader.readLine()) != null){
    shaderSource.append(line).append("/n");
}
```

"/n" was changed to "\n" and the code compiled! Thank you for a speedy fix of my own stupidity.

Comment: It means you have a syntax error. You've included something after a pre-processor directive that shouldn't be there. What? Who knows - you haven't posted your code.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to find out if there was an obvious answer before posting my code all haphazardly. Ill edit my question

Comment: This is probably an issue with your loader code. Maybe you read it line by line (which will remove the newlines), so the GLSL compiler will see everything as a single line.

Comment: Thank you for your extremely accurate answer haha. I appended "/n" instead of "\n". Yeah, kind of a rookie.

Comment: Upvoted because this helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shader code needs a newline at the end of each line.

But this says an array of null terminated strings:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glShaderSource

Comment: `glShaderSource` will simply concatenate all strings in the array you give it. It will **not** add any newlines at all. The intention is not to be able to specify each line of the shader as a separate string (although you can do that), but do be able to easily combine shader sources consisting of different parts. Sencond note: Shader code does **not** need much newlines. Like C, newlines are required for preprocessor directives and the // comments. The rest can be written in a single line, if you like...